# Why is DFS not suited for shortest path problem?

Tags: shortest-path, weighted-graphs, dijkstras-algorithm, depth-first-search

I am sorry for the repetition of the question. I understand that this question has already been answered before by the community, but most answers tend to focus on unweighted graphs. I want to know **Can DFS we used to find the shortest path for weighted graphs?** I know that Dijkstra's algorithm is used to find the shortest path for weighted graphs. **But, what I want to know is what is fundamentally different in using DFS for unweighted graphs compared to Dijkstra (which is BFS + priority queue/set) and why can't we create DFS + priority queue/set implementation for shortest path problem?**

Ref link: [Shortest Path using DFS on weighted graphs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/80797/shortest-path-using-dfs-on-weighted-graphs),
[Why can't DFS be used to find shortest paths in unweighted graphs?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/4914/why-cant-dfs-be-used-to-find-shortest-paths-in-unweighted-graphs)

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Every unweighted graph is also a weighted graph (just set all the weights equal to 1). Clearly, if DFS cannot find shortest paths in unweighted graphs it also cannot find shortest paths in weighted graphs.

Comment: What would a "Dfs + priority queue" be? DFS is characterized by the use of a stack (I.e. making a choice from the last vertex chosen) otherwise, it's not a dfs

Comment: I simply meant that when we put something in the stack or making a recursive call we do it as per some criteria or heuristic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TL;DR Depth First Search

I believe that *Depth First search* traverses the graph by recursively visiting the unseen vertices of the current vertex until they're exhausted.

```
for all vertices fresh = true
DFS(v):
   v.fresh = false
   for all the neighbors e of v:
      if e.fresh:
         DFS(e)
```

Now, weight on the other hand, is *a restriction imposed on edges*. Hence, the usage of *Breadth First Search* becomes handy. Because we traverse the graph based on *layers* or *levels*, where we're checking all the edges at a certain vertex.

## Dijkstra's algorithm

Dijkstra's algorithm is pretty much tricky. You seen, the original paper does specify how *prioritize to vertices based on the sum of the weight for each reached vertex*.

But more importantly, it does **not** specify how to fulfill such a task. Indeed, the whole time complexity is dependent on the complexity of how we're prioritizing the vertices.

### Prioritizing the vertices

Consider an abstract data type `PriorityQueue`, where it supports the following operations for an instance `queue`:

- `void add(item)` to add an item to the instance `queue`
- `item get()` to return and remove the current top priority from the instance `queue`.

Many data structures provide these elementary operations. But the bottleneck of the algorithm is **to update the vertex's priority** in case it was reached from a less weighted edge.

Consider an operation `update(item,value)` that reset the priority of the `item` to a certain `value`. There are many ways to extend `PriorityQueue` but all of them have different complexities.

#### Using Arrays

Arrays are finite contiguous chunks of memory, so we have

- $O(1)$ to `add()` any item at the end, $O(n)$, otherwise since it involves swapping.
- $O(n)$ to `get()` the current priority because we traverse the whole array.
- $O(n)$ to `update()` any item for the same reason.

#### Using Heaps

Heaps are arrays that have a binary tree property, called the *heap invariant* which states the following

> *Every node is less than it's children (in the case of a MinHeap)*

This provides $O(\log_2 n)$ to both `add()` and `get()` an item. But it costs $O(n)$ to `update()` any item's priority (since there is no order imposed on the children).

#### Using Binary Search Trees (Balanced)

It has the same costs as the heap does for both to `add()` and `get()` an item. But instead of $O(n)$ to `update()`, we have $O(\log_2 n)$. Since searching throughout the whole tree is logarethmic due to the following properties

> *Every node is greater than its left*
>
> *Every node is less than or equals its right*

#### Using Fibonacci heaps

[Fibonacci heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap) are an advanced data structure that is a forest of MinHeap trees.

Comment: (`visiting the unseen vertices` would seem the way of traversals. I'm confident I could code *breadth first* using recursive calls.)(I consider it pointless to specify a logarithm base in "Big-O notation".)

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER**SCIENCE** @SE.

Comment: Thanks, @greybeard! I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Got it thanks! @0x0584